# How to visual block all the content in Vim

Tags: vim

What is the command for visual blocking the entire content in Vim? I couldnt find a question here. Please feel free to point it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>ggVG</kbd>

- <kbd>gg</kbd> gets you to the first line in the file, from anywhere in the file.
- <kbd>V</kbd> begins Visual selection, line-based, so it will grab whole lines.
- <kbd>G</kbd> gets you to the last line in the file.

Comment: This is a vim palindrome, which is to say that if you reverse the command you get the same result: `GVgg`